# Django custom tag: Inclusion tag with no context

Tags: django, django-templates

I've read through the [custom tags and filters documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/), but I'm not seeing how this can be done. I want to make a custom tag that just renders a string. No context, just the same string literal every time. In this particular case, I would prefer this over putting {% include 'hello_world.htm' %} all over the place:

```
Foo, foo foo
<br>
{% hello_world %}
<br>
bar bar bar
```

Renders to:

```
Foo, foo foo
<br>
"Hello World"
<br>
bar bar bar
```

I feel like I should be able to do this with something like:

**custom_tags.py:**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('hello_world.htm')
def hello_world():
     return {}

# Or:

def hello_world():
     return {}
register.inclusion_tag('hello_world.htm', takes_context=False)(hello_world)
```

No dice. I have other custom tags in custom_tags.py, I am loading them and they work fine, but always getting

```
Invalid block tag: 'hello_world', expected 'endblock' or 'endblock content'
```

The documentation says

> Tags are more complex than filters, because tags can do anything.

... how do you do the simplest thing possible with tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#shortcut-for-simple-tags

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def hello_world():
    return u'Hello world'
```

then in your template you can write `{% hello_world %}` to render the string.

Comment: No he's, using an inclusion tag because he's also rendering a template.

Comment: Yes that's what he was doing but the question states "I want to make a custom tag that just renders a string" and that is what my solution provides.